# Как проверить на наличие в объекте и отрисовать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

не получается отрисовать необходимые данные
Ко мне приходит такая переменная `currentCarBrand`.
И есть объект, в зависимости от значение переменной `currentCarBrand` необходимо отрисовать нужные данные

```
const entities = {
    opel: [
      {
        label: 'astra',
        icon: '',
      },
    ],
    mercedes: [
      {
        label: 'GLA',
        icon: <gla />,
      },
      {
        label: 'GLE',
        icon: <gle />,
      },
    ],
    bmw: [
      {
        label: 'x1',
        icon: <bmwx1 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'x2',
        icon: <bmwx2 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'x3',
        icon: <bmwx3 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'x4',
        icon: <bmwx4 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'x5',
        icon: <bmwx5 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'x6',
        icon: <bmwx6 />,
      },
    ],
    audi: [
      {
        label: 'q1',
        icon: <audiq1 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'q2',
        icon: <audiq2 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'q3',
        icon: <audiq3 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'q4',
        icon: <audiq4 />,
      },
      {
        label: 'q5',
        icon: <audiq5 />,
      },
    ],
  }
```

пробовал отрисовать с помощью такой функции, но не до конца понимаю как это сделать

```
const renderCarGroup = () => entities.hasOwnProperty(currentCarBrand).map((item) => (
    <ListItem>
        <Car>
          {item.icon}
          {item.label}
        </Car>
    </ListItem>
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` показывает, есть ли в объекте свойство. Чтобы получить значение свойства, нужно обратиться к нему так - `entities[currentCarBrand]`.

```
const renderCarGroup = () => {
  if (entities.hasOwnProperty(currentCarBrand)) {
    return entities[currentCarBrand].map((item) => (
      <ListItem>
        <Car>
          {item.icon}
          {item.label}
        </Car>
      </ListItem>
    ))
  }
}
```